# django url.py error page not found

Tags: python, django

I can't make `url.py`. It still shows page not found.

These are my urls:

```
/pins/tag/?search=A/
/pins/tag/?search=B/
/pins/tag/?search=C/
```

`A,B,C` are variable strings.

This is my `urls.py`:

```
url(r'^pins/tag/?search=(?P<tag>(\w|-)+)/$')
```

How do I make a correct `urls.py`?

Comment: Your url is not handled by any view. What are you expecting with that code?

Comment: Hello, Thank you for your response. Actually you don't need to view.

Comment: (?P<tag>(\w|-)+)/$') is mapping to A,B,C. But, I can't handle it

Comment: So you are asking for a regex? if not what we need is your views.py

Comment: @heybro Check the answers below. You need to call a view to handle your url.

Answer (score 1):

Regex like this would match anything except newline character  `(.*)`. So your URL should look something like this. If you just want Uppercase alphabets stick to [A-Z]

```
url(r'^pins/tag/?search=(?P<tag>.+)/$', views.search_tag , name='search_tag'),
```

views.py

```
def search_tag(request, tag):
    #do whatever here with tag
```

Answer (score 0):

I mapping the url like this in my projects

url(r'^pins/tags/(?P[\w.@+-]+)/$', 'what_app_search', name='search')

Give me a feel back if it resolve the mapping.